# Summing Properties Across Subheadings (Org-Mode)

Tags: org-mode

Suppose our cursor/point it located on the first line of `Parent Task` in the following:

```
* Parent Task
:PROPERTIES:
:END:

** Sub-Task A
:PROPERTIES:
:TALLY: 2
:END:

** Sub-Task B
:PROPERTIES:
:TALLY: 8
:END:
```

**Question:** Is there a way to write a function which (i) sums the `:TALLY` sub-properties from `Sub-Task A` and `Sub-Task B` and (ii) inserts them into the `:TALLY_SUM` property of `Parent Task`?

I know that for part (ii) we can use the org-mode property API function `(org-entry-put "TALLY_SUM" <sum>)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function should do the job:

```lisp
(defun org-sum-tally-in-subtree ()
  "Add up all the TALLY properties of headings underneath the current one
The total is written to the TALLY_SUM property of this heading"
  (interactive)
  (org-entry-put (point) "TALLY_SUM"
                 (number-to-string 
                  (let ((total 0))
                    (save-excursion
                      (org-map-tree
                       (lambda ()
                         (let ((n (org-entry-get (point) "TALLY")))
                           (when (stringp n)
                             (setq total (+ total (string-to-number n))))))))
                    total))))
```

Two points to note:

1. All sub-headings below the current point are searched, not just the next level down
2. The code does not enforce that `TALLY` should be an integer, so it also works for float values

Example:

```
** Parent Task
:PROPERTIES:
:TALLY_SUM: 22.201
:END:

Do =M-x org-sum-tally-in-subtree= here

*** Sub-Task A
:PROPERTIES:
:TALLY: 4
:END:

**** Sub-sub task
:PROPERTIES:
:TALLY:    10.001
:END:

*** Sub-Task B
:PROPERTIES:
:TALLY: 8.2
:END:
```